# How do I enable a font?

Tags: font, font-book

Every time I enable a font in FontBook.app, it works well. But if I logout or restart Mac, the font is disabled again. I tried many times but it doesn't get better.

For example, "Songti SC" and "STSong" are reset to be disabled once I logout or restart.

Is there any solution that can fix the problem?

Comment: Do you have duplicates of these fonts installed?

Comment: @xeophin I suppose not. When I check duplicates using FontBook.app, it tells me 'No Duplicates Found'. And another thing I noticed is that 'SongTi SC' and 'STSong' are in the same __.ttc__ file. If I click the __.ttc__ file to install it, 2 install windows will be shown. And if I install one of them, both will be installed.

Comment: What version of os x are you talking about?

Comment: @TomGewecke It's Mac OS X 10.8.4

Comment: Is there any other font where you have this problem than the two you mentioned?

Comment: @TomGewecke Yes, I tried to enable some fonts which are disabled by default, they are all disabled again when I logout. Fonts I tried: 'PT Sans Caption', 'PT Sans Narrow', 'STKaiti', 'Nanum Pen Script'.

Comment: Try creating a new user account and see if you have the same problem when you log in to that one.  PT is for Russian and Nanum is for Korean and the others are for Chinese.  Do you write in all those languages?